# Making the matrix raining html canvas animation ascend instead of descend

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I've been messing around the Matrix raining canvas animation [here](http://cog.cs.drexel.edu/ci101/graphics/) and was wondering if it was possible to make it rain upwards instead of downwards. I've tried using the rotate() method and it basically skews and sort of stretches the canvas. Any advice?

code:

```
 var numberOfColumns = 50;
 var pixelsPerColumn = width / numberOfColumns;

 var columnY = [];
 for (var i=0; i<numberOfColumns; i++) {
      columnY[i] = randomInt(0, height);
 }

 var characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*";
 c.font = "12px Courier";

 function step() {
     c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)";
     c.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
     c.fillStyle = "#0f0";
 for (var i=0; i<numberOfColumns; i++) {
     var r = randomInt(0, characters.length);
     var char = characters.substring(r, r+1);
     c.fillText(char, i*pixelsPerColumn, columnY[i]);
     columnY[i] += pixelsPerColumn;
    if (columnY[i] > height) {
     columnY[i] -= height;
    }
 }
}
loop(step, 100);;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

```
columnY[i] -= pixelsPerColumn; //subtract instead of add
if (columnY[i] < 0) { //if less than zero (the top)
  columnY[i] += height; //add height instead of removing it
}
```